# NodeMailer through error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465

Tags: node.js, nodes, nodemailer

I try many solutions but none of them work. I will use this to send mail to everyone through custom domain mail who are login using my app

I have used the following js code in index.js to integrate app and adapter

```
const express = require( 'express' );
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const nodemailer = require( 'nodemailer' );

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( {
    service: 'smtp.CustomDomain.mail',
    port: 465,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'XYC@CustomDomain.com',
        pass:'123'
    }
} )

let  message = {
  from: "XYC@CustomDomain.com",
  to: "XYZ@gmail.com",
  subject: "Message title",
  text: "Plaintext version of the message",
  html: "<p>HTML version of the message</p>"
};

app.get( '/', (req,res) =>
{
    transporter.sendMail( message, (error,info) =>
    {
        if ( error ){
            console.log("Something went wrong",error)
        }
         if ( info )
        {
            console.log("Mail send successfully")
        }
    })
} )

app.listen( port, () =>
{
    console.log("Server is running on port "+port)
})
```

Here is the error message

```
Server is running on port 5000
Something went wrong Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```